# How to send link/url to confirm user registration and/or password reset/recovery using ASP.Net MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, registration, forgot-password

I see it all over the place, yet, I could not find one example about this (maybe I don't know the proper wording), I am trying to build using ASP .Net MVC2 (but any example on just ASP .Net would be also helpful) a process that will send a link to the user at the end of the registration process to let him confirm his registration. Also, a similar process to let the user to reset his password, with the typical "forgot password" and send a link/url so that the user can click and type a new password. Can someone help me to either find an example or at least to let me know how to "google" it?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

For the forgot password, you can make a view like this

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>

<p><%: ViewData["Error"] %></p>
<p> Have you forgotten you password? No problem!</p>

<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.Label("Fill in your username") %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBox("userName") %>
</div>

 <p> and <input type="submit" value="click here" /> to reset your password.</p> 

<% } %>
```

and as a controller (first make an model from the aspnetdb (if you don't see it press the 'show all files' button))

This must be placed right after the controller definition

```
aspnetdbEntities aspnetdb = new aspnetdbEntities();
```

Then follows this

```
public ActionResult ForgottenPassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ForgottenPassword(FormCollection formValue) 
{ 
   var userName = formValue["userName"];
   try
        {
            var useraccount = aspnetdb.aspnet_Users.Single(c => c.UserName == userName);
            var fromAddress = "put an email-address";

            var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, user.Email)
            {
                Subject = "",
                Body = "a link to a controller that lets the user put in a 
                        new password and then save that password to the aspnetdb."
                        (that controller will most likley require a username)
                        "or a link with a new random password in it tht you have put
                        as his password like this:"
                        useraccount.aspnet_Membership.Password = "random password";
                        aspnetdb.SaveChanges;

             };

            var client = new SmtpClient("smtpServerName");
            client.Send(message);

            return View();
        }

        catch
        {
            ViewData["Error"] = "Please give up an existing username";
            return View();


        }
    }
```

I hope this answer was helpfull.